# How to bitmask a number (in hex) using the AND operator?

Tags: logic, bitmask

I know that you can bitmask by ANDing a value with 0. However, how can I both bitmask certain nibbles and maintain others. In other words if I have 0x000f0b7c and I wanted to mask the everything but b (in other words my result would be 0x00000b00) how would I use AND to do this? Would it require multiple steps?

Answer (score 7):

You can better understand boolean operations if you represent values in binary form.

The AND operation between two binary digits returns 1 if both the binary digits have a value of 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Suppose you have two binary digits ***a*** and ***b***, you can build the following "truth table":

```
  a | b | a AND b
 ---+---+---------
  0 | 0 |    0
  1 | 0 |    0 
  0 | 1 |    0
  1 | 1 |    1
```

The masking operation consists of ANDing a given value with a "mask" where every bit that needs to be preserved is set to 1, while every bit to discard is set to 0.
This is done by ANDing each bit of the given value with the corresponding bit of the mask.

The given value, 0xf0b7c, can be converted as follows:

```
f    0    b    7    c     (hex)
1111 0000 1011 0111 1100  (bin)
```

If you want to preserve only the bits corresponding to the "b" value (bits 8..11) you can mask it this way:

```
f    0    b    7    c
1111 0000 1011 0111 1100
0000 0000 1111 0000 0000
```

The value 0000 0000 1111 0000 0000 can be converted to hex and has a value of 0xf00.

So if you calculate "0xf0b7c AND 0xf00" you obtain 0xb00.

Comment: Got it! Would this work for any situation? In other words, would ANDing a byte with 0xf always maintain it?

Comment: The value 0xf in binary is 1111, or, if you represent it as a byte (8 bits), 00001111. ANDing a **byte** with 00001111 (0xf) would preserve only the 4 least significant bits (the 4 on the far right), while if you AND a byte with 11111111 (0xff) you basically obtain the original byte. I encourage you to practice these operations with a hex-bin converter (the Windows "calc" can do this).